# Error: primef not initialized?

Tags: c++, prime-factoring

When I run this code I get the error: variable primef not initialized, but I think it is (unless I don't properly understand c++)
Also, how efficient is my code in terms of processing power used?
Here is the code:

```
/*
This program finds the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143
Written by Jay Schauer
*/

//Data Declarations
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int number = 600851475143; //stores the number
    int primef; //stores the largest prime number
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        cout << "Number: " << number << endl;
        cout << "i: " << i << endl;
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            number /= i;
            primef = i;
        }
        cout << "Largest prime factor: " << primef << endl;
    }
    cout << "Largest prime factor: " << primef << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't properly understand C++, I guess. What makes you think it's initialized? If `number % i` is not `0` then you'll print the uninitialized value.

Comment: No, `primef` is not initialized. Why do you think it is? Compare its definition with `number`.

Comment: As for efficiency, it's pretty much as inefficient as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `number` is even, `primef` is initialized to 2 the first time through the loop. However, if `number` is odd, `primef` is not initialized the first time through the loop, because the `if` fails, so when you try to write it in the last statement of the loop it has never been initialized.

Your algorithm is not particularly efficient. Here's pseudocode for something better; it finds all the factors, and their multiplicities, not just the largest:

```
function factors(n)
    f := 2
    while f * f <= n
        while n % f == 0
            output f
            n := n / f
        f := f + 1
    if n > 1 then output n
```

That's still not particularly efficient, but better than yours. Once you get that working, the next step up in efficiency is to eliminate factors of 2 separately, then trial divide only by odd `f`.

You should have noticed that you have the same report of the largest prime factor in two different places in your code. That's a clue that something is wrong. Which one should you remove?

Comment: So I just changed primef = 0;

Comment: to int primef = 0 so I don't get that error. But now it only prints out "Largest Prime Factor: 0, and doesn't seem to run the code

Comment: What is the largest number that can be stored in an `int`?